# Calculate "age" from date/time table

Tags: visual-studio, m

I have a Date/Time column in format "13.10.2020 06:08:43" and I need to calculate the "age" from current time. Output should be like from given example: "4h" since its 10:08 atm - Date/Time column was 4h ago. I need this to be in M language to use in visual studio 2019.

I used:

```
let

        Source = Sql.Database("xxxx", "xxxxx", [Query="SELECT#(lf)#(tab)storeid as 'Shop'#(lf)#(tab), concat('SCO', posnr) as POS#(lf)#(tab),  concat(datediff(hour,[LastTransactionDate]#(lf)#(tab), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),' h') as 'Age'#(lf)#(tab), POSIPaddress as 'IP'#(lf)#(tab),[PosNr]#(lf)    ,[AdapterPosOrGroupId]#(lf)    ,[UpdatedOn]#(lf)    ,[LastTransactionDate]#(lf)    ,[LastStartDate]#(lf)    ,[Open]#(lf)    ,[Locked]#(lf)    ,[CashDisabled]#(lf)    ,[IsCashEnabled]#(lf)    ,[CashDevicesTraficLight]#(lf)    ,[POSIPAddress]#(lf)    ,[ScoPosServiceVersion]#(lf)    ,[WinScoVersion]#(lf)    ,[StoreType]#(lf)FROM [LaneEventDatabase ].[dbo].[POS.LaneCurrentState]"]),
        #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [CashDevicesTraficLight] = "green" then 1 else if [CashDevicesTraficLight] = "yellow" then 2 else if [CashDevicesTraficLight] = "red" then 3 else 4),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"Custom", type number}})
    in
        #"Changed Type"
```

which works just great but visual studio doesnt like the way source is handled and while deploying gives me error:

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model.

'.
```

Comment: What is required output if it is more that 24 hours?

Comment: it should continue, after 24h should come 25h etc. This SQL command does this exactly how needed but I need it to work in VS also so I could upload my tabular model:



SELECT
 storeid as 'Shop'
 , concat('SCO', posnr) as POS
 ,  concat(datediff(hour,[LastTransactionDate]
 , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),' h') as 'Age'
FROM [xxxxx ].[dbo].[xxxxx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new **Custom Column** using this below code-

```
= Text.From(
    (Duration.Days(DateTime.LocalNow()-[date]) * 24) +
    Duration.Hours(DateTime.LocalNow()-[date])
) & "h"
```

Here is sample output-

[image]

Comment: This works up until 24h. for Date : "12.10.2020 09:46:16" I get output as "1.00:05:42.7340186" I'm not sure how to turn this into hours

Comment: Hi @user245255, I have updated my answer. This should work now.